# Can I have more than one OAuth Domain?

Tags: bug, feature-request, oauth2

I tried to set more than one OAuth Domain, but seems to it's not working. I tried to set them separated by comma or space, but got `redirect_uri - must be under an apps registered domain` error message.

There is this same question with no answer: [Can we specify more than one OAuth Domain?](https://stackapps.com/questions/7630/can-we-specify-more-than-one-oauth-domain)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Apps! Thanks for finding that question, but doesn't that make your question a duplicate?

Comment: @Glorfindel, seems to my question is duplicate. But original question is 3 years old and have no answers(

Comment: My experience the past few years is that the API only gets updates when a major Stack Exchange feature changes, e.g. the new close reasons or the renaming of Favorites to Bookmarks. I don't think they do new features like this anymore, sorry :(

Comment: Is there any solution to this?