# Redirect URI for a chrome extension using StackExchange API Oauth

Tags: support, api, oauth2, chrome-extensions, extension

I'm working on a developing a [browser extension](https://stackapps.com/q/9515/96492) which uses StackExchange API [authentication](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/authentication). I was able to successfully implement the authentication for Microsoft edge/Chrome when I added `chromiumapp.org` as the `OAuth Domain` in the [app settings](https://stackapps.com/apps/oauth) & `redirecturi = browser.identity.getRedirectURL('oauth2')` as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31169304/6908282).

But this doesn't work with Firefox since the domain `chromiumapp.org` is specific to chromium browsers. The domain for Firefox is `allizom.org`. And its [not possible to add multiple domains](https://stackapps.com/q/7630/96492) to the StackApp in app settings.

1. So as suggested in the questions [here](https://stackapps.com/a/6531/96492) & [here](https://stackapps.com/a/7813/96492), I tried adding **`stackexchange.com`** as the `OAuth Domain` in [app settings](https://stackapps.com/apps/oauth) & `redirect_uri = https://stackexchange.com/oauth/login_success`, but this create another issue (*similar to [this](https://stackapps.com/q/3156/96492) & [this](https://stackapps.com/q/7666/96492)*),

   where, when the user clicks the login button, a new window is opened for the authorization which lets the user login to stack overflow. And once the login is successful, the **window should automatically close**. But the window gets redirected to the `https://stackexchange.com/oauth/login_success` which is the `redirect_uri` and gets stuck there. (*below screenshot*)

   I tried the same in a new instance of a browser which lets me login to using Google/GitHub OAuth, but even that returns to the same page an gets stuck there.
2. I'm also wondering if using the domain `chromiumapp.org` or `allizom.org` is secure at all! As mentioned in [this answer](https://stackapps.com/a/6531/96492), it sounds like a security concern.

Can anyone please help with solving this issue?

[image: OAuth screen - Authorizing Application]

---

Comment: You can register 2 apps, one for the chromiumapp.org and one for the  allizom.org oauth domain.  Not ideal but if nothing betters comes up it might be the workaround.

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm working on right now, but I was hoping to have one single app.

Comment: I'm also wondering if using the domain `chromiumapp.org` or `allizom.org` is secure at all! As mentioned in [this answer](https://stackapps.com/a/6531/96492), it sounds like a security concern.

Comment: So while you say it is "stuck" you're also sure the url doesn't have the access_token as fragment (end of the url after the #) added. Because that might look like you're on the same  page but if only the fragment changed nothing visible will happen on the page.

Comment: A new window is opened for the authorization which lets the user login to stack overflow. And once the login is successful, the window should automatically close. But the window gets redirected to the page in the [screenshot above](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qq9Os.png) and gets stuck there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution that I'm currently using for one of my applications is to have 2 different "Stack Apps", with different OAuth Domains - one for the `chromiumapp.org` and one for the `allizom.org`.

This is the only way that's working for me.